# Bootstrap child opacity cannot overwrite opacity set in a parent

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to set one opacity in a  parent container and overwrite it in a  child container but it does not seem to work

```
<div class="card bg-dark" style="opacity: .4">
    <div class="bg-light border-2 p-4 m-5 rounded" style="opacity: 1 !important;">
       ...
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm stomped. What am I missing?

Comment: Probably want to use rgba instead of opacity: https://meetanshi.com/blog/opacity-vs-rgba/

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to do a thing either.

Comment: Both the child and the parent opacities are set correctly. If you want to have the child visible, the parent needs to be visible as well.

Comment: rgba: https://jsbin.com/feteyorapi/1/edit?html,output